# In calculation of Maximum power transferred for reactive circuits why is this done?

Tags: circuit-analysis

We are trying to find the value of the impedance for which power transferred to the load will be maximum.

Let

$$v(t) = V_mcos(\omega t+ \theta_v)$$

$$i(t) = I_mcos(\omega t+ \theta_i)$$

Then

$$ P=  \frac{1}{2} V_mI_mcos(\theta_v-\theta_i) $$

For a purely resistive circuit

$$ P= \frac{1}{2}V_mI_m= \frac{1}{2}I_m^2R = \frac{1}{2}|\mathbf I|^2R$$

---

Finding the Current through the load

$$ \mathbf I = \frac{\mathbf V_T}{(R_T+ jX_T)(R_L+jX_L)}$$

To find the average power, why do we use the following equation

$$ P=  \frac{1}{2}|\mathbf I|^2R = \frac{|\mathbf V_T|^2R_L/2}{(R_T+R_L)^2(X_T+X_L)^2}$$

(as 
$$ \frac{1}{2}|\mathbf I|^2R $$

the power for a purely resistive circuit.)

(instead of)

$$ P=  \frac{1}{2} V_mI_mcos(\theta_v-\theta_i) $$

Answer (score 1):

First I'll set the two equations equal to each other. 
$$ \frac{1}{2}| I|^2R = \frac{1}{2} V_mI_mcos(\theta_v-\theta_i) $$

Since \$V = IR\$, we can substitute the \$V_m\$ in the right hand side for \$I_mR\$. which becomes:

$$ \frac{1}{2}| I|^2R = \frac{1}{2} I^2R cos(\theta_v-\theta_i) $$

Since there are no reactive components to the circuit, the current and the voltage are perfectly in sync, which means:

$$ \theta_v = \theta_i $$
when you subtract the two, you will get zero, and so:
$$ cos(\theta_v-\theta_i) = cos(0) = 1$$
when plugging that into the equation it becomes 
$$ \frac{1}{2}| I|^2R = \frac{1}{2} I^2R $$

Since (for real numbers) \$x^2 = |x|^2 \$, and current is only a real number. 
$$ \frac{1}{2} I^2R = \frac{1}{2} I^2R $$
We can show that **the two equations you are calling into question are in fact the same equation**, one is simply simplified to account for the entirely real nature of a non-reactive circuit.

Comment: Sir we are considering maximum power transfer for reactive loads

Answer (score 0):

maximum power is delivered when voltage and current are in phase, but due to reactive components the two are out of phase so power computation involve the phase difference between the two